# How can I drop multiple indexes from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, outliers, drop

```py
fm2_age = fm1_age.drop(fm1_age.index[(fm1_age > df['age'].median() + 35)])

fm2_age = fm2_age.drop(fm2_age.index[(fm2_age < df['age'].median() - 15)])
```

How can I simplify these lines onto a single one, I tried using this code but it doesn't seem to work

```py
fm2_age = fm1_age.drop(fm1_age.index[(fm1_age > df['age'].median() + 35) &(fm2_age < df['age'].median() - 15)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dropping, you can filter for what you want to keep:

```py
keep = df['age'].median() + [-15, 35]
fm1_age[fm11_age.between(*keep)]
```